# requests_mock NoMockAddress Exception

Tags: python, https, requests-mock

I'm currently trying to do unit tests using the requests_mock library in order to patch requests.
I've written the following code:

```
def test_general_search(requests_mock):
    params = {'query': 'testsetset', 'exact': 0, 'max_pages': '1', 'category': 'username'}
    requests_mock.get(f'{MOCK_ADDRESS}', json=MOCK_RESPONSE)
    client = Client(MOCK_ADDRESS, auth=MOCK_CREDS, headers=MOCK_HEADERS)
    res = general_search(client, params)
    assert ...
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
requests_mock.exceptions.NoMockAddress: No mock address: GET https://fake-url.com/search?query=username%3Atestsetset&page=1
```

Can anyone help me out with figuring out how to solve it? I've used mock as a pytest feature.

Comment: I made code like this work with `MOCK_ADDRESS = 'https://fake-url.com/search'`. Please could you say what `MOCK_ADDRESS` is in your code? My guess is that your `MOCK_ADDRESS` maybe does not have `/search` or similar.

Comment: what is MOCK_ADDRESS?

Answer (score 12):

This occurs when something about the mock request

in this case

```
requests_mock.get(f'{MOCK_ADDRESS}', json=MOCK_RESPONSE)
```

does not match *exactly* the get request of the code being tested. So I'd say you need to print out both the URL in the test class and the one in the tested code.

For example, I was getting the same error, until I did something like

```
    @requests_mock.Mocker(kw='mock')
    def test_get_data_from_endpoints(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['mock'].get('http://testurl.org', json=response_1)
```

More info here: https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matching.html#query-strings

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a custom matcher that performs a match on the request's URL not including the querystring.

The documentation isn't very clear on how to go about this, but after breaking my head for a while I was able to put together [this article](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/additional-custom-matchers-for-requests-mock-mocking-in-python-2ae13847f32c) explaining how custom matchers for `requests_mock` work.

A custom matcher simply returns whether the request matched or not, for your use case you can even configure a single matcher to check for different URLs, or partial URLs, based on the URL in the request being matched.

The sample I created will hopefully make it clear enough for your use case:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
import requests_mock


def a_matcher(request):
    # will match the base url with any query string
    parts = urlparse(request.url)
    base_url = parts.scheme + "://" + parts.netloc + parts.path
    if base_url == "http://www.example.com/path/to/the/magic":
        return True
    return None


def b_matcher(request):
    # will only match exactly
    if request.url == "http://www.example.com/road/to/hell":
        return True

    return None


def test_calls_made_out_of_order():
    status_code_a = int(HTTPStatus.OK)
    status_code_b = int(HTTPStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mocker:
        mocker.post(
            requests_mock.ANY,
            additional_matcher=a_matcher,
            status_code=status_code_a,
        )

        mocker.post(
            requests_mock.ANY,
            additional_matcher=b_matcher,
            status_code=status_code_b,
        )

        response_b = requests.post(
            "http://www.example.com/road/to/hell",
            headers={
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            json={
                "data": {
                    "b": True,
                }
            },
        )

        assert response_b.status_code == status_code_b

        response_a = requests.post(
            "http://www.example.com/path/to/the/magic?foo=bar",
            headers={
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            json={
                "data": {
                    "a": True,
                }
            },
        )

        assert response_a.status_code == status_code_a
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue recenlt. I'm not sure of the reason. Maybe this can help someone.

- Error

```py
MOCK_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:12345/"

def test_http_with_requests_mock(requests_mock):
    HTML_RESPONSE = "<html><body><h1>Some error!</h1></body></html>"
    requests_mock.get(MOCK_SERVER_URL + "/endpoint", text=HTML_RESPONSE)
[...]
```

- Fix. Replaced the value of the variable to a single string

```py
def test_http_with_requests_mock(requests_mock):
    HTML_RESPONSE = "<html><body><h1>Some error!</h1></body></html>"
    requests_mock.get("http://localhost:12345/endpoint", text=HTML_RESPONSE)
[...]
```